# How to set new value for the environment variable in VSTS

Tags: powershell, automation, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

we have used the env:msg merge but it did take the default value in variables tab. We were unable to assign a value.Even though we see the value in the previous step

[image]

The code that assigns the value

```
$env:msgmerge = 'Git Merge to Master After Deployment Repo:' + "$(reponame)"
Write-Output $env:msgmerge
```

Environment variables created with $env: are Process variables, so they're lost when the process exits and we can't access them from another process (PowerShell instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh this solved we need to use the vsts method

```
$msgmerge = 'Git Merge to Master After Deployment Repo:' + "$(reponame)"
Write-Output $msgmerge

Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=msgmerge;]$msgmerge")
```

Comment: What's the point of using `Write-Host`?  Your problem was with environment variables.

Comment: Even then, why are you using `Write-Host` and not `Write-Output`?  At least `Write-Output` would let you do something with what is returned.

Comment: Seems you want to set new value for the environment variable. And use the new value for the task group (after PowerShell task). So you do should use `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=variablename]value"`.You can also refer the powershell script in the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/variables?tabs=powershell#custom-variables.